# Test Scores Demo C++

Tags: c++

I was assigned to do a program that takes 6 scores, drops the lowest score then takes the average of the highest 5 scores. I don't understand why I can't get lowest variable to be used properly in my calcAverage function.

```
      #include <iostream>
        #include <iomanip>
        using namespace std;


void getScore(int &Score);
void calcAverage(int, int, int, int, int, int, int &lowest);
int findLowest(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5, int s6, int &lowest);


int main()
{

    int s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, lowest; 

    // Call on getScore function to iterate through each of the six scores
    getScore(s1);
    getScore(s2);
    getScore(s3);
    getScore(s4);
    getScore(s5);
    getScore(s6);

    // Call the calcAverage to display average of five highest scores
    calcAverage(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, lowest);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}


void getScore(int &Score)
{
    cout << "Please enter a test score (Value betweent 1 and 100): ";
    cin >> Score;

    // Validate the score input
    while (Score < 1 || Score > 100)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input, Please enter a test score value from 0 to 100! ";
        cin >> Score;
    }
}

int findLowest(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5, int s6, int lowest)
{

    lowest = s1;

    if (s2 < lowest)
        lowest = s2;
    else if (s3 < lowest)
        lowest = s3;
    else if (s4 < lowest)
        lowest = s4;
    else if (s5 < lowest)
        lowest = s5;
    else if (s6 < lowest)
        lowest = s6;

    cout << "The lowest test score is: " << lowest << endl;

    return lowest;

}


void calcAverage(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5, int s6, int &lowest)

{
    int findLowest(int, int, int, int, int, int, int);
    double avg;

    findLowest(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, lowest);


    avg = ((s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6) - lowest) / 5.0;


    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "The average of the five highest scores is: " << avg << endl;

}
```

Comment: Think what happens if `s1` happens to be the highest grade.

Comment: Your `findLowest()` function will fail in many cases the way you have it.  You need to get rid of the `else`'s to make it work correctly.

Comment: Note: Find lowest is `lowest = std::min({s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6});` (C++11)

Comment: You should try setting break points at each of your else if checks in findLowest if you aren't understanding why it fails in a lot of cases. Do this and make s1 your highest number and when you step through you'll see how it leaves prematurely.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```
    int findLowest(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5, int s6, int &lowest);
    ...
    int findLowest(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5, int s6, int lowest)
    {
...
void calcAverage(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5, int s6, int &lowest)

{
    int findLowest(int, int, int, int, int, int, int);
```

Note the lack of & in the definition.  That should match the declaration.  The second declaration (matching the wrong definition) should not be there at all.  I assume you added the second declaration to get rid of a compile time error that you misunderstood.

Edit:  Others pointed out the other error (using `else if` when you wanted just `if`) that is revealed once you fix the error I described.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of JSF points to a problem, that you need to solve.

A note of style: You declare findLowest much too often. Declare it once, define it once and use it as often as you like. But assume the data (10,7,5...)

```
lowest = s1;

if (s2 < lowest)
    lowest = s2;
else if (s3 < lowest)
```

lowest is 10 in the first line.

Then s2 is < 10 so lowest = 7.

Now s3 is < 7, but it won't get executed as it happens in the else branch and s2 < lowest was true.

In the end you have the wrong value.

Another note of style: You have a function that takes 6 input parameters and caculates one value from that. That's a use case to not pass a reference but simply return that value, which you do anyway.

```
int findLowest(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5, int s6);
```

and call it as

```
lowest=findLowest(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6);
```

that will clear your brain of references, `else` statements and multiple function declarations.